# Global overhead of -fPIC on mips32 realease 2

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, overhead, mips32, fpic

It is [well-know](http://www.technovelty.org/c/position-independent-code-and-x86-64-libraries.html) using the overhead added by asking position independent code when compiling code for linux target varies according to the architecture.
The most well-know example is the difference between x86_32 (aka IA32) and x86_64: unlike x86_32, the added overhead is negligible for x86_64.

***I know for X86, but what is the overhead for mips32 big endian?***

Comment: Since MIPS uses PC-inset Jump-And-Link (and jump--but most jumps are short enough to use Branch if EQual R0 R0) rather than PC-offset, PIC calls would presumably use JALRegister (similar to the Global Offset Table solution for shared libraries). (In addition to the instruction overhead, on a branch target buffer miss, JAL targets can be available earlier in the pipeline than JALR,so there might be some additional performance loss.) The ISA also lacks convenient PC-relative addressing, which might affect addressing globals outside the 64KiB accessible relative to the Global Pointer.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton : The gcc man page say Jal is only used with -mlong-calls . Also I forgot to say that I even don't know how non pic addressing work on this arch. :| So, according to you there is an overhead: but it don't really tell how much can be the average. (I asked this question because I got an error while compiling gcc. I wanted to know the overhead if I compile gcc with lto with -fPIC. It stay still open for other programs (which I may use in the future))